# Submit form with Event Listener

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form:

```
<form name="form" action="#">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <span id="error_name"></span>
    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <span id="error_email"></span>
    <input type="email" name="user_mail" id="mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <span id="error_msg"></span>
    <textarea name="user_message" id="msg"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and I am trying to submit the form without onsubmit="return validation()" I want to do that with an addEventListener I tried this, but it didn't work:

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);

```
function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    if (name == "" || email == "" || message == "") {
        var error = document.createElement('p').textContent = "*This Field is Required";
        document.getElementById('error_name').innerHTML = error;
        document.getElementById('error_email').innerHTML = error;
        document.getElementById('error_msg').innerHTML = error;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

It returns  Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, how can I make it work and submit with addEventListener?

Comment: You do not have `id` set to the `form`. Should be `<form id="form" name="form" action="#">`

Comment: Thanks, that was it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get element by 'id' form but you do not have an element with 'id' 'form'.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

So why don't you give this form an id

```
<form name="form" action="#" id='form'>
```

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);

function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    if (name == "" || email == "" || message == "") {
        var error = document.createElement('p').textContent = "*This Field is Required";
        document.getElementById('error_name').innerHTML = error;
        document.getElementById('error_email').innerHTML = error;
        document.getElementById('error_msg').innerHTML = error;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="#" id="form">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <span id="error_name"></span>
    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <span id="error_email"></span>
    <input type="email" name="user_mail" id="mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <span id="error_msg"></span>
    <textarea name="user_message" id="msg"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```